# npm install getting stuck after upgrading node v18.16.0

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

Facing issue while doing npm install with node 18.16.0
Then npm i is getting stuck for ever(tried till one hour)
Tried verbose logging and posted the same here
The packege.json looks like

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^14.1.3",
    "@ngrx/store": "^14.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "positioning": "^2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.6",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.6",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.1.3",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^14.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.9.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "karma": "^6.3.4",
    "shx": "^0.3.3",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4"
  },
```

getting stuck for more than an hour , the verbose logging looks like

```
> demoapp@6.0.0 install
> npm install

npm verb cli /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm
npm info using npm@9.5.1
npm info using node@v18.16.0
npm verb title npm install
npm verb argv "install"
npm verb logfile logs-max:10 dir:/Users/demoapp/.npm/_logs/2023-05-27T07_13_33_786Z-
npm verb logfile /Users/demoapp/.npm/_logs/2023-05-27T07_13_33_786Z-debug-0.log
npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 2237ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcore 19ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/codelyzer 9ms (cache hit)

> demoapp@6.0.0 install
> npm install

npm verb cli /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm
npm info using npm@9.5.1
npm info using node@v18.16.0
npm verb title npm install
npm verb argv "install"
npm verb logfile logs-max:10 dir:/Users/demoapp/.npm/_logs/2023-05-27T07_13_37_333Z-
npm verb logfile /Users/demoapp/.npm/_logs/2023-05-27T07_13_37_333Z-debug-0.log
npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 2239ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcore 36ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/codelyzer 6ms (cache hit)

> demoapp@6.0.0 install
> npm install

npm verb cli /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm
npm info using npm@9.5.1
npm info using node@v18.16.0
npm verb title npm install
npm verb argv "install"
npm verb logfile logs-max:10 dir:/Users/demoapp/.npm/_logs/2023-05-27T07_13_40_908Z-
npm verb logfile /Users/demoapp/.npm/_logs/2023-05-27T07_13_40_908Z-debug-0.log
npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 2265ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcore 18ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/codelyzer 9ms (cache hit)

> demoapp@6.0.0 install
> npm install

npm verb cli /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm
npm info using npm@9.5.1
npm info using node@v18.16.0
npm verb title npm install
npm verb argv "install"
npm verb logfile logs-max:10 dir:/Users/demoapp/.npm/_logs/2023-05-27T07_13_44_548Z-
npm verb logfile /Users/demoapp/.npm/_logs/2023-05-27T07_13_44_548Z-debug-0.log
npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 2252ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcore 16ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/codelyzer 9ms (cache hit)

> demoapp@6.0.0 install
> npm install

npm verb cli /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm
npm info using npm@9.5.1
npm info using node@v18.16.0
npm verb title npm install
npm verb argv "install"
npm verb logfile logs-max:10 dir:/Users/demoapp/.npm/_logs/2023-05-27T07_13_48_106Z-
npm verb logfile /Users/demoapp/.npm/_logs/2023-05-27T07_13_48_106Z-debug-0.log
```

Tried

1. Deleting the node module
2. Deleting the npm cache.

Note : works fine with node 14.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

node 18.16.0 is not tested with NPM install. Check this documentation for NPM: https://docs.npmjs.com/integrations where you can install the missing utils for this package of yours.

Comment: The actual problem was in my install script. There was no obvious issue with Angular 14 and Node 18.